# PHP intersection of two strings (server directory path and url path)

Tags: php, string

I have a situation where I need to find the overlap between the server directory path and the public path in which a project is based.

```
$dir = '/server/home/this/directory/to/public/my_app/';
$uri = '/my_app/home/script.php';
```

I looked all over for an answer and found partial solutions.

I can split the strings by '/' and make arrays, and then use array_intersect(), however I get this...

```
$dir_array = array_filter(explode('/', 'a/e/c/d/'));
$url_array = array_filter(explode('/', 'd/e'));
print_r( array_intersect($dir_array, $url_array) );
// Array ( [1] => e [3] => d )
```

I don't want to include the 'home' folder because it's not in the URI.

Answer (score 1):

This is my approach. I haven't tested if it's faster than @Adam's but  I think it looks cleaner.

```
$dir = $_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME'];
$uri = parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], PHP_URL_PATH);

$intersection = implode('/',
    call_user_func_array('array_intersect',
        array_map(function($a) {
            return explode('/', $a);
        },
            [$dir, $uri])
    )
);

$uri_result = substr($request_uri, strlen($intersection));
```

Answer (score 0):

So I came up with an answer:

```
$dir_a = array_filter(explode('/', __DIR__));
$url_a = array_filter(explode('/', $uri));
$base_public_folder = '';

foreach ($url_a as $url_key => $url_f) {
    foreach ($dir_a as $dir_key => $dir_f ) {
        $next_url_f = !empty($url_a[($url_key + 1)]) ? $url_a[($url_key + 1)] : '';
        $next_dir_f = !empty($dir_a[($dir_key + 1)]) ? $dir_a[($dir_key + 1)] : '';
        if (
            $url_f == $dir_f &&
            ($next_dir_f == '' || $next_url_f == $next_dir_f)
        ) {
            $base_public_folder .= "/".$url_f;
            break;
        }
    }
}
echo $base_public_folder;
// outputs '/my_app'
```